# How can I approach data split across multiple databases?

Tags: django, database

I'm putting together a proposal for the development of a web application.

The app is to be launched in multiple countries, and some of the client's partners and (allegedly; I'm no lawyer) some of the countries involved have rules about where personal data can be stored. The upshot is that there is a hard requirement that particular data about certain countries' users is stored on servers in that country. (It sounds like they're OK with me caching data in any country, though -- so I intend to have a Redis in-memory store in the main data centre.) Some of the data (credit card details, for example) will additionally be encrypted, but this seems to make no difference to them in terms of where it can be stored.

With the current set of requirements, users from one country won't actually ever interact with users from another country, so one obvious option is to run different instances of the application in each country, entirely self-contained. This is simpler from an architectural point of view, but harder to manage, and would have overall higher server costs. It might get complicated if for example the client wants reports on all users across all countries, or eventually they want to merge the databases, and users' primary keys have to change. Not impossible, but it'd likely be a pain.

Probably better would be to have a central database with all information the client deems it acceptable to host in a single spot (North America somewhere), and then satellite databases in each country holding the information the client needs to be kept "at home".

So the main database would have the main users table, consisting of only a PK and a country code, and would have lots of other tables. Each local database would have a "user details" table, with a foreign key (to the main users table on the main database) and a bunch of other columns of personally identifiable information, as well as username, email address, password, etc.

The client may then push to have other data stored in the satellite locations, some of which may be one-to-many with a user or many-to-many with a user.

My questions:

- How can this be handled with Django? Can it, or should I look at other frameworks?
- Can the built-in User model be edited to look in all the satellite databases for the matching User model on log in, and when logged in to retrieve the user data from those databases without too much trouble?
- Are there any guidelines you can give me to make sure code stays simple and things stay efficient?
- Will this be significantly easier if the satellite database only has one-to-one data with the main User table? I imagine that having one-to-many or many-to-many data in those satellite databases would be a major pain (or at least inefficient), or am I wrong?

Comment: Rather than splitting your tables, you might be able to keep your models the same and just run different database instances. You could then use a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) to dynamically determine which database to use for a given query (based on some model field, say).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions accordingly:

1. Looks like something that you could do in Django (I like Django so I may not be the best to opinion here) - maybe the following will convince you (or not).
   A microservice approach? Multiple instances of the "user" resource multiservice each with it's own database (I heard you about the costs but maybe?).
2. You can do plenty with Django Authentication Backends ([including wirting your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/)) - there is a "remote" auth backend you could use as an example. Read about stateless authentication (JWT).
3. Look at points 1 and 2.
4. Consider [not using the built-in Django user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) is it doesn't suit you.

Comment: Microservices for authentication and storage/retrieval of the personal info do not seem like a suitable approach to me. I was more wondering about Django having simultaneous connections to multiple databases, and how well it copes with that.

Comment: Multiple database connections are supported out of the box. Although I don't see that being very suitable for your case.

Comment: And why is that? Do they expect exactly the same sets of data to exist on each connection or something?